# Move files to specified directories based on text in file's name

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

this may seem like a simple question but it's been a long time since i last did some scripting and I'm a novice in bash scripting so i apologize.

I need to download a large amount of picture files from a server and then organize them based on the picture file's name, in this instance the picture files are pages and i need to move them into directories which are chapters.

An example of a picture file name will look like this
"0080-002.png"

0080 = chapter
002 = page

so if the file is "0080-***.png" move it into directory "chapter-80".

This is what i have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir BOOK
cd BOOK
mkdir chapter-{1..80}

wget SOME_URL/00{01..80}-0{1..90}.png

for file=$(ls | grep *.png | cut -c1-4) in ~/BOOK/ do
```

I have thought about using an incremental variable
but i wouldn't really know how to do that since the variable is "$file"

-Sorry for my inexperience and if you have any advice id appreciate it, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

url="SOME_URL"
dir="BOOK"

[ "$dir" ] && mkdir -p "$dir" || dir=.

# avoid cd in scripts
#cd BOOK
#mkdir chapter-{1..80}

# sure? this could take ages
wget "$url"/00{01..80}-0{1..90}.png -P "$dir"

# avoid parsing ls
for file in "$dir"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9].png
  do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    subdir="${file%/*}"
    fname="${file##*/}"
    chapt="$(printf 'chapter-%02.0f' "${fname%%-*}")"

    # only existing chapter on need
    mkdir -p "$subdir/$chapt"

    mv "$file" "$subdir/$chapt"
done
```

Comment: refer to [2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) see *${parameter%[word]}*

Comment: This completely works but it just needed 1 edit because of my mistake with pages "0{01..90}". I really appreciate it. I have a lot to learn so i really appreciate you giving me a reference.